# Parsing JSON Object to Restful web service

Tags: java, php, android, json, rest

I am developing an android registration system that communicates with a mysql database through JSON. The restful web service was written with PHP and Slim library. i have tested the web service using Advanced Rest Client App by parsing a json payload data into it and it works perfectly fine with the result shown below. At the moment i am trying to parse user data from the android app to the server and it shows this error `(Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <html><head><title>Slim of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject)`. I would someone to tell me what i am doing wrong coz i feel the error is from my **JSONParser** class and **Userfunction**. Thanks in advance.

Here is my test result

> {"tag":"signup","success":1,"error":0,"uid":"547d92b0480711.90973742",
>   "result":{"firstname":"mish","lastname":"harry","email":"mishael19@gmail.com"}}

Here is JSONParser

```
public class JSONParser2 {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser2() {
}

public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params){

    try{
        if(method.equals("POST")){
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }else if(method == "GET"){
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }


    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;    
}
}
```

here is my Userfunction

```
public class UserFunctions {

private JSONParser2 jsonParser2;

private static String signupURL = "http://globalpadtutorials.globalpad.info/loginSignup/v1/signup";

private static String signup_tag = "signup";

private static String postMethod = "POST";

public UserFunctions(){
    jsonParser2 = new JSONParser2();
}

public JSONObject signupUser(String fname, String lname, String email, String pwd){

    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", signup_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstname", fname));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastname", lname));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pwd));

    JSONObject json = jsonParser2.makeHttpRequest(signupURL, postMethod, params);
     Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
    return json;
}
}
```

Error stack

```
12-02 11:04:19.681: E/JSON Parser(10024): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <html>   
<head><title>Slim of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

PHP code

```
function createUser(){

$request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
$resp = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->response();
$resp['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
$body = $request->getBody();
$users = json_decode($body);
$dbhandler = new DbHandler();
$tag = $users->tag;
$fname = $users->firstname;
$lname = $users->lastname;
$email = $users->email;
$pwd = $users->password;

$response = array("tag" => $tag, "success" => 0, "error" => 0);

if($tag == 'signup') {
    if ($dbhandler->userExisted($email)) {
        $response["error"] = 2;
        $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed";
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        $result = $dbhandler->addUser($fname, $lname, $email, $pwd);
        if ($result != false) {
            $response["success"] = 1;
            var_dump($result);
            $response["uid"] = $result["user_id"];
            $response["result"]["firstname"] = $result["firstname"];
            $response["result"]["lastname"] = $result["lastname"];
            $response["result"]["email"] = $result["email"];
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            $response["error"] = 1;
            $response["error_msg"] = "An error occured during sign up";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
} else{
    $response["error"] = 1;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Invalid tag request: ".$tag;
    echo json_encode($response);
}
}
```

html error

Slim Application Errorbody{margin:0;padding:30px;font:12px/1.5 Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;}h1{margin:0;font-size:48px;font-weight:normal;line-height:48px;}strong{display:inline-block;width:65px;}

## Slim Application Error

The application could not run because of the following error:

### Details

**Type:** ErrorException**Code:** 8**Message:** Trying to get property of non-object**File:** /home/globa390/public_html/globalpadtutorials/loginSignup/v1/index.php**Line:** 63

### Trace

```
#0 /home/globa390/public_html/globalpadtutorials/loginSignup/v1/index.php(63): Slim\Slim::handleErrors(8, 'Trying to get p...', '/home/globa390/...', 63, Array)
12-02 11:55:50.366: E/JSON(27492): #1 [internal function]: createUser()
12-02 11:55:50.366: E/JSON(27492): #2 /home/globa390/public_html/globalpadtutorials/loginSignup/library/Slim/Route.php(462): call_user_func_array('createUser', Array)
12-02 11:55:50.366: E/JSON(27492): #3 /home/globa390/public_html/globalpadtutorials/loginSignup/library/Slim/Slim.php(1326): Slim\Route->dispatch()
12-02 11:55:50.366: E/JSON(27492): #4 /home/globa390/public_html/globalpadtutorials/loginSignup/library/Slim/Middleware/Flash.php(85): Slim\Slim->call()
12-02 11:55:50.366: E/JSON(27492): #5 /home/globa390/public_html/globalpadtutorials/loginSignup/library/Slim/Middleware/MethodOverride.php(92): Slim\Middleware\Flash->call()
12-02 11:55:50.366: E/JSON(27492): #6 /home/globa390/public_html/globalpadtutorials/loginSignup/library/Slim/Middleware/PrettyExceptions.php(67): Slim\Middleware\MethodOverride->call()
12-02 11:55:50.366: E/JSON(27492): #7 /home/globa390/public_html/globalpadtutorials/loginSignup/library/Slim/Slim.php(1271): Slim\Middleware\PrettyExceptions->call()
12-02 11:55:50.366: E/JSON(27492): #8 /home/globa390/public_html/globalpadtutorials/loginSignup/v1/index.php(12): Slim\Slim->run()
12-02 11:55:50.366: E/JSON(27492): #9 {main}
```

Comment: You got response as html, so you cant parse it as json )

Comment: @Suvitruf how do u change it to json? i have added my php code

Comment: first, show the html. In makeHttpRequest print to log     json variable

Comment: @Suvitruf the html error i am getting has been added to my question

Comment: @Suvitruf it appears that line 63 in my php file is $tag = $users->tag; pls how do i resolve it?

Answer (score 3):

```
 public JSONObject signupUser(String fname, String lname, String email, String pwd){

      List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
      params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", signup_tag));
      params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstname", fname));
      params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastname", lname));
      params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
      params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pwd));

      String jsonstr = jsonParser2.makeHttpRequest(signupURL, postMethod, params);
  //cast String into jsonobject
  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
  return json;
```

}

Comment: in this code to convert String into JSON object JSONObject json=new JSONObject(jsonStr); jsonStr is response

Answer (score 1):

Your [url](http://globalpadtutorials.globalpad.info/loginSignup/v1/signup) returns **html** page with 404 error. That's why you cant parse it as json.

Comment: Suvitruf, thanks, how do i resolve the 404 error, coz it seem to work when it test it?

Comment: @mish it's not error on your Android code, cause even with curl you got this error, so it's you web server error.

Comment: @mish it's administration problem, i think. Not programmatic.

Comment: i just comfirmed wat u said and is correct. I tried changing the Slim post method to get and it echo some string. it seems like there is an issue with the post method on the server

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue. Ask your Server admin for the permissions for using the database for both web and mobile. After that paste your php files in public_html.

Comment: where are you hosting your files?

Comment: i am hosting my files at hosting24.com

Comment: you should check the url then. Also talk to hosting24 people regarding accessing the permissions. They will provide you the steps.